# How to import variable from another script?

Tags: python, variables, import

I'm building a quadcopter which runs on python.

`script1` is a process which lets me control the speed of 4 motors.

`script2` should be a process which regulates the motors in order for my quadcopter to be stable.

I have a variable `motorspeed` in `script1.py` and I would like to import it to `script2.py`. I tried

`from script1.py import motorspeed`,

however this only starts `script1.py` and doesn't execute `script2`. As `script1.py` is a while-loop, `script2.py` never gets executed. The while-loop does end, when I press a button (which shutsdown the quadcopter), so I need to run `script2.py` while `script1.py` is running. How can I get the variable `motorspeed` in `script2.py` to increase and decrease the speed of the motors?

Comment: You'll need to show a minimal abstraction of your code that shows the problem.

Comment: Note that you don't include the `.py` - the module you're importing from could be either a file or directory. If there is a `while` loop in `script1.py` that starts even when it's being imported and never ends, how did you ever expect to get anything out of it?

Comment: `from script1 import motorspeed` if both are in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to send the motor speed from a running `script1.py` to  a running `script2.py`, right?

**Note:** importing something from a file does *not* run that file as a separate process!

To make running programs exchange data, you have to

1. Run the programs
2. set up *interprocess communication* ("IPC") or shared memory between them.

There are al least three ways to start two scripts so they run concurrently.

A) From the command line;

```
python script1.py &
python script2.py &
```

B) with `subproces`. In `script1.py` do;

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.Popen(['python', 'script2.py'])
```

C) with `multiprocessing`

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import script2

p = mp.Process(target=script2.main)  # Assuming script2 has a main function.
p.start()
```

*How* to do IPC depends on how you start the scripts.

You could use [sockets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sockets.html) as a means of communication in all three cases. You would have to set up `script2` as a server on a chosen port number (say 12345). If `script1` would like to increase or decrease the motor speed, it would connect to port 12345 and send a message containing the new motor speed. Except from the linked howto, there are many socket tutorials out there and a detailed answer would be too long here.

If you choose to use `multiprocessing` (option C), you could use a shared memory [`value`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

```
# script1
import multiprocessing as mp
import script2

motorspeed = mp.Value('d', 0.0)
p = mp.Process(target=script2.main, args=(motorspeed,))
p.start()
```

Of course `script2.main` should recognize one argument!
*Both processes* can now manipulate the `motorspeed` object.

If it is undesirable that `script2` can also change `motorspeed` you could set up a [`Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

```
# script1
import multiprocessing as mp
import script2

parent_conn, child_conn = mp.Pipe(duplex=False)
p = mp.Process(target=script2.main, args=(child_conn,))
p.start()
motorspeed = 23.6
parent_conn.send(motorspeed)
```

In this case, `script2.main` should regularly *read* the messages!

All in all, I would suggest going the `multiprocessing` route, since it has the easiest ways of setting up communication.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
from script1 import motorspeed
```

Based on what you described, you just want to change the speed at real time. So basically you shouldn't put a while loop in your `script1`. The `script1` should only focus on the controlling put (interfacing with the machine). Then in your `script2` (the main in your case), you should put your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple processes. You're just looking for some basic concurrency (i.e. doing multiple things at the same time without one blocking the other) for which you can use threads.

`script1.py`:

```
from threading import Thread

motorspeed = 0

def control_speed():

    # I'm doing this to stick to your question, but prefer using a class
    global motorspeed

    while True:
        motorspeed += 0.01

# This runs control_speed 'in the background'
Thread(target=control_speed).start()
```

`script2.py`:

```
from time import sleep

# from script1 import motorspeed will not work
import script1

while True:
    sleep(1)
    print(script1.motorspeed)
```

Output of running `script2.py` for a few seconds:

```
91131.589991
191556.080026
283986.210112
384517.350206
```

Comment: Note that in Cpython only one thread at a time can be executing python bytecode. So if the thread representing `script1` is running, the thread representing `script2` can be doing I/O but *cannot* run. That might have undesirable consequences in such real-time tasks.  So in this case it is probably better to use separate processes. Using processes would also mean that you could e.g. rewrite `script2` in C should Python prove too slow for the task.

Comment: @RolandSmith two processes can only improve the speed by up to a a factor of about 2. If OP's code cannot calculate fast enough in my solution to control the quadcopters properly then he needs a better algorithm, not multiprocessing. OP should start by writing the simplest code that works and move on to more complex solutions when needed, rather than prematurely optimising.

Comment: The first part of my comment is about *concurrency*, not speed.

Comment: @RolandSmith the two concepts are interlinked. More concurrency is only needed if each section needs more time to run, i.e. is not running fast enough. The threads will switch extremely quickly and and if they execute their own code fast enough this will work fine.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that "The threads will switch extremely quickly". That depends on the Python version and on how the OS schedules threads. In short, GIL contention and thread starvation can be a real problem in Python 2, while the GIL in Python 3 can get hung up on I/O. Read [Understanding the GIL](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf) by David Beazley for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running both scripts at the same time, importing a variable in one script might the get you the value you actually expected. You would have to start both scripts and manage some interprocess communication in order to pass the variables.

Or you could use a Message Queue like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ in order to do that.

This code architecture doesn't feel right. You don't import variable from one python script to another. Instead you could put the functionality of speed_control of motors as a function in one script as a function and then import that function in to the second function.

Split modules according to functionality and put them in functions.
Then in the main python file which is you execute, you could call the function, speed_control(), when required.

I am no expert in quadcopter, but let me suggest the following architecture for python code.

Suppose you put the motor_speed_control function in a module named msc.py and the functionality of getting sensor data in sense.py.

Now in stability.py, you could keep checking sensor data such as yaw or pitch in a while loop and if the condition satisfies, execute the speed_control() function you imported. The idea of splitting these functionalities into modules is to aid with building and maintaining them.